# groovy spock test unable to find java class in same package

Tags: java, maven, groovy, spock

Im pretty new to spock testing and ive come across a hairy problem which i cant figure out.. Im not sure what ive done wrong

I have a simple java class

./src/main/java/com/twg/sample/model/PrimeNumberCalculator.java

```
package com.twg.sample.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Service
public class PrimeNumberCalculator {

    public int[] getPrimeNumbers(int end) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, end)
            .filter(number -> !IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number / 2).anyMatch(i -> number % i == 0))
            .toArray();
    }
}
```

and i have a simple groovy spock test
./src/test/groovy/com/twg/sample/model/PrimeNumberCalculatorSpec.groovy

```
package com.twg.sample.model

import spock.lang.Specification


class PrimeNumberCalculatorSpec extends Specification{

    def "test prime numbers"(){
        given:
        def primeCal = new PrimeNumberCalculator()

        expect:
        [1, 2, 3, 5, 7] == primeCal.getPrimeNumbers(9)
    }

}
```

Im using intelliJ and after i mar the src/test/groovy folder as source test root, the test runs fine. However when i do

mvn clean install 
the test fails

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.5:testCompile (default) on project prime-number-calculator: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: startup failed:
[ERROR] C:\development\prime_number_calculator\src\test\groovy\com\twg\sample\model\PrimeNumberCalculatorSpec.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class PrimeNumberCalculator
[ERROR]  @ line 10, column 24.
[ERROR]            def primeCal = new PrimeNumberCalculator()
```

why cant the groovy test find the java class which is in the same package?
my groovy plugin is

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a very strange Surefire quirk.

This does **not** work:

```xml
<include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
```

Instead any of these does work:

```xml
<include>**/*Spec.java</include>
<include>**/*Spec.class</include>
<include>**/*Spec.*</include>
```

Funny, eh (especially the first variant)? I have not checked if there is an open Surefire ticket for it. You may want to create one and report back here in a comment.

**Alternative solution:** What I always do is name my Spock tests to end with `*Test` (Surefire) or `*IT` (Failsafe). This way I do not need any includes and it will work in projects with mixed Java and Groovy tests.

Comment: but it does run the test.. Just that it fails to find the java classes in the same package

Comment: No, it does not run the test, it cannot even compile it (goal _testCompile_ fails). Please show your full POM or share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub so I can reproduce the error.

Comment: BTW, I stopped using GMaven Plus long ago because I always had problems in connection with IDEs. I use Groovy Eclipse from Maven and have also configured my IDEs to use it, so both IDE and Maven use the same compiler.

Comment: At first I was also using GroovyEclipse, but since two years I've switched over to GMaven Plus and I didn't experience any problems with recent versions of of it, and I'm using it in 10+ Projects. YMMV, but if you are using IDEA I'd say us GMaven. I would also recommend to just follow the surefire/failsafe conventions of using `*Test`/`*IT` as endings as you added as alternative solution.

Comment: I do use IDEA, but also Eclipse. The problems occurred mostly in a complex IDEA project, though, and for the whole team I was coaching at the time. The problems were recurrent but hard to reproduce and happened when recompiling projects after local changes, feature branch switches or similar. They went away when we switched to Groovy Eclipse. Maybe new GMaven Plus versions are better than the one 1.5 years ago or IntelliJ IDEA got refactored in that part meanwhile. I do no longer have access to my former client's code base anymore, I cannot test. But that was just a sideshow here, anyway. :-)